# JSON file shows extra backslashes after appending a new object to an array

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a school.json file with this structure:

```json
{
  "schoolConfig": [

      {
        "schoolTypeCode": "C1",                
        "schools": [
          {
            "schoolId": 456,                  
            "config": [
              {
                "name": "Classes",
                "value": [
                  {
                    "id": 1                           
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 2
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "schoolId": 123,                   
            "config": [
              {
                "name": "Classes",
                "value": [
                  {
                    "id": 11                            
                  }                  
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "schoolTypeCode": "C2",                
        "schools": [
          {
            "schoolId":50,                    
            "config": [
              {
                "name": "Classes",
                "value": [
                  {
                    "id": 12
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "schoolId": 10,                  
            "config": [
              {
                "name": "Classes",
                "value": [                  
                  {
                    "id": 10
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }    
  ]
}
```

I want to append to the JSON file which will change the config values for any filtered result.  So, for example, the output JSON will have:

```json
"value": [
  {
    "id": 1                           
  },
  {
    "id": 2
  }
  {
    "id": 5
  }
]
```

The c# code written to replace the existing json with the new one is:

```cs
string json = File.ReadAllText(jsonFilePath);
dynamic jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
JToken classes = jsonObj.SelectToken("$.schoolConfig[?(@.schoolTypeCode == 'C1')].schools[?(@.schoolId == 456)].config[?(@.name == 'Classes')]");

List<JToken> appList = classes["value"].ToList();

var itemToAdd = new JObject();
itemToAdd["id"] = 5;
appList.Add(itemToAdd);

classes["value"] = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(appList).ToString();

string output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
File.WriteAllText(jsonFilePath, output);
```

The file gets modified except that the value is shown in one line (with no indentation or formatting) as

```
"value": "[{\"id\":1},{\"id\":2},{\"id\":5}]"
```

How do I ensure that the JSON file does not show extra backslashes before the quotes and is rendered in proper format as written above. Please advise.

Comment: You use `classes["value"] = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(appList).ToString();` to set value to a string. That is why you get the output you have. value is now a string, that is why the quotes will be escaped with backslash.

Comment: @trenki - What would you suggest to append the new item in filtered result and in existing json file if not serialze of list object?

Comment: Just put `appList` straight in as is: `classes["value"] = appList;`

Comment: @Charlieface: This gives me error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken>' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken'

Comment: Yeah you need a `JArray` try this `classes["value"] = new JArray(appList.ToArray<object>());` but personally I would create it as a `JArray` in the first place and not use a `List`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are extracting the `value` array from the `classes` object as a `List<JToken>` instead of as a `JArray`.  Then you are serializing the list to a string before adding it back to `classes`.  If you just cast it to `JArray` instead of converting it to `List<JToken>`, you can modify the `JArray` directly.

Change this line:

```
List<JToken> appList = classes["value"].ToList();
```

to this:

```
JArray appList = (JArray)classes["value"];
```

and remove this line:

```
classes["value"] = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(appList).ToString();
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TO2zqt